# Laravel extend or use Traits dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, traits

It is possible to extend or use different class during run time?

Example:
Let say we have a `model` called `Player` (Our A -model)

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Player extends Model{

}
```

And we have 2 other models (**B and C models**)

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

protected $connection= 'db_b';

class PlayerInfoB extends Model{
    function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Our C model

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

protected $connection= 'db_c';

class PlayerInfoC extends Model{
    function getName(){
        return $this->name_g;
    }
}
```

How Model `A (Player)` can extend `Model B or C` during run time based on configuration or other data

Why I need this.
I have a 2 or more different tables, this tables columns have different names, so for example:

```
Table 1 - name

Table 2 - name_g

Table 3 - name_full
```

So I need a wrapper that I can always call `getName()`, without checking what table is used now.

```
$player = Player::get();

echo $player->getName();
```

If something is not clear, please comment and I will update my question.

**Update** based on [madalin-ivascu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4613398/madalin-ivascu) answer can be done this way?

```
class Player extends Model{
    protected $model;          

    public function __construct(){

        $this->setModel();

        parent::__construct();


    }
    protected function setModel(){
        $this->model = $this->column_model_name
    }
    function getAttributeName(){
        return $this->model->getName();
    }

}
```

Comment: based on what you decide the correct name?

Comment: @madalinivascu For example in `players` table I will have column `model` with value like `PlayerInfoC` or `PlayerInfoB`

Comment: It is not possible to compose a calss at runtime without using `eval` or or dirty hacks. You have to reconsider your class design, because it's very unlikely that you need to do that with a good design.

Comment: then use that model value to call the function

Answer (score 0):

use that model value to call the function

```
$player = Player::get();

echo Player::getName($player->id,'PlayerInfoC');
```

in the Player model you simply call

```
public static function getName($id,$class)
   return $class::where('player_id',$id)->getName();//each class will have the function
}
```

ps: you will need to do some validation to test if the class exist with that name

another option will be to create relationships between the models

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer, I've updated my question.

Comment: I can add dynamic relation?

Comment: what kind of dynamic relation are you talking about?

Comment: I mean I can set relation during run time?

Comment: why do you need it a run time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156534/discussion-between-froxz-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to compose a calss at runtime without using eval or or dirty hacks. You have to reconsider your class design, because it's very unlikely that you need to do that with a good design.

What you can do is changing table and db connection at runtime on the model instance using methods `setTable` and `on`:

```
Player::on('db_b')->setTable('player_info_b')->find($id);
```

Another approach (preferable) would be defining the model `PlayerInfoC` and `PlayerInfoB` that extend your `Player` model, and then based on your condition you instantiate the class `B` or `C` when needed.

Comment: Hi I don't need to compose a modal, modal is there I just need to use different trait dynamically or extend dynamically to access methods on C and B from A

Comment: What actually you want to do is declaring the contents of a class at runtime. And this is not possible in PHP without using `eval` which i highly discourage.

Answer (score 0):

In your code your script must have a state that you check in order to know when to use the correct model?

In this case why not use a parameter in get name?

```
class Player extends Model{

    function getName($field){
        return isset($this->{$field}) ? $this->{$field} : null;
    }

}
```

If you do this a lot then use magic methods:

```
class Player extends Model{

    function __get($key){

        return isset($this->{$field}) ? $this->{$field} : null;
    }

}

...

echo $myModelInstance->{$field};
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

In Laravel when you have pulled data back via a collection method it does this magic method anyway since all attributes are stored in a nested object called attributes so the __set() and __get() looks something like this:

```
function __get($key){

    return isset($this->attributes->{$key}) ? $this->attributes->{$key} : null;

}

function __set($key, $value){

    return $this->attributes->{$key} = $value;

}
```

The latter with attributes sub set is advised, this way you prevent data conflicts with database column names returned vs names you have already used in a model.
This way you only have to manage one attribute name as a reserved name in every model you create and not worry amount the hundreds of var names you use overwriting another in a model or extension of a model.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with booted method same as below in your model:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    if (<--your condition-- >) {
        $traitInitializers[static::class][] = 'boot' . ExampleTrait::class;
        $traitInitializers[static::class][] = 'boot' . Organizations::class;
    }
}
```

$traitInitializers is a variable defined in model of Eloquent and you can modify it same as above to append your trait dynamically .